# 4 way video for pyramidal hologram

Tags: rendering, video

I struggle with one thing. I need to create a 4 way video for a pyramidal hologram. How can I do it using blender? I have tried to search everywhere but seems that Im not hitting the correct keywords.

[Please see example of such video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pan7fgDkxY)

Thank you Mike

Comment: Have you considered using third party video editing software?

Comment: Sure I did, thats why I came across blender :-) I assume that there must be a function within the which will copy and rotate the clip.

Comment: can you append your model/scene you want to render "pyramid style"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Transform Effect

Transform strip effect is the way to manipulate input strips around the "canvas". As stated by the Blender Manual [page](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/strips/effects/transform.html):

> Transform is a swiss-army knife of image manipulation. It scales, shifts, and rotates the images within a strip.

Select the given video strip and add several **Tranform effect** strips to it (the must all be referred to the input, the one in blue, so always pick it before adding each effect).

[image]

You'll not need to duplicate the strip several times, as the effect strip is already a copy of the input video itself, but with custom parameters.

Make sure to assign a **Over drop** blending mode to each tranform strip and mute the input one.

---

If you are planning to use multiple views (as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFhhIOaGW7U)), just assing a transform strip to each input video:

[image]

The 4 input videos were made by rendering the same animation from 4 different cameras:

[image]

---

You can find several templates for Blender at: [DIY hologram using a 4-sided pyramid](http://rimstar.org/science_electronics_projects/hologram_pyramid_diy_homemade.htm)

Comment: Thank you Carlo! You are a star! You have resolved my problem.